# Adapter not displaying data in ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am doing following thing:

1- Activity1 (sending an array List) to Activity 2
2- Activity 2 (showing the list in ListView using custom adapter) and passing array list to third activity
3 Activity 3 (Adding more values in arrayList and passing it back to activity 2)

Now everything is working fine except when I pass back this array list from activity 3 to 2. It do not add new modified array List. Yes, it passes the array list correctly. I have tested it using Debug.

I am using following code for ListView

In Activity 2

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.receiptsListView); 

         adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, myArrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) 
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {
         if (requestCode == ADD)
         {
            Custom= (ArrayList<Custom>) data.getSerializableExtra("arrayList");
            addArryaListInListView();
         }
        }
    }

    private void addArryaListInListView()
    {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Please tell me what should i do instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Can u give the code of CustomArrayAdapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (requestCode == ADD)
         {
            Custom= (ArrayList<Custom>) data.getSerializableExtra("arrayList");
            addArryaListInListView();
         }
```

in Above code you got the data from ACtivity , but you missed out main thing you did't add it to adapter.. i think the data should be added to adapter thn you should say `notifyDataSetChanged()`  , but i don't see it here..

Comment: i am doing this         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @user966227.. i know , but before doing that the array list you got should be added to adapter.. if you can show some more code we can help.. right now i dont know what is **Custom**..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the lisAdapter once again when the data's are changed

listView.setAdapter(adapter);